# Using reflection to retrieve a value from a list

Tags: c#, linq, generics, azure

I have a simple method which retrieves a table from an azure mobile service.

```
public static async List<T>GetDataFromListTable<T>()
{
    var data = await MobileService.GetTable<T>().ToListAsync();
    return data.Count != 0 ? data : null;
}
```

This works fine.

What I am trying to do is have another method that takes a parameter name which is returned from the service and return the value of that parameter. So far I have this

```
public static async Task<T> GetDataFromTable<T>(string paramName)
    {
        var k = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        var members = typeof(T).GetProperties().Select(t=>t.Name).ToList();
        if (!members.Contains(paramName))
            return (T)k;
        var mn = typeof(T).GetProperties()[members.IndexOf(paramName)];
        var data = GetDataFromListTable<T>();
        var retval = data.Select(t => t.mn);
    }
```

The issue is obviously that I can't do the Linq query as T doesn't contain mn. I can also not use

```
var retval = data.Select(t=>t.paramName);
```

as paramname is a just a string representation of a member within a class.

In a nutshell...

method 1 has the parameter name, grabs a list from method 2. From the returned list in method 2, find the parameter name and return the associated value.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905823/how-to-get-value-of-a-definite-column-name-in-c-sharp-linq/22905946#22905946

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
var retval = data.Select(t => mn.GetGetMethod().Invoke(t, null));
```

or

```
var retval = data.Select(t => mn.GetValue(t, null));
```

---

You can also simplify your code with something like this (not tested, sorry):

```
public static async Task<T> GetDataFromTable<T>(string paramName)
{
    var k = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    var mn = typeof(T).GetProperty(paramName);

    if (mn == null)
        return (T)k;

    var data = GetDataFromListTable<T>();
    var retval = data.Select(t => mn.GetGetMethod().Invoke(t, null));

    ...
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. I thought it would be possible, but I've never really dabbled in reflection before now - it's somewhat powerful!

Comment: Shouldn't `GetDataFromTable<T>()` *actually* return something? ;-)

Comment: It depends if you want it to compile I guess ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think using expression trees would be more convenient since you're working with collections. Your method signature needs to incorporate the types `T` and `TResult` since it is using `Select` which returns an `IEnumerable<TResult>`.

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> SelectData<T, TResult>(
    string propertyName
)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<TResult>();
    }

    var dataTask = GetTableData<T>();

    var tType = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
    var property = Expression.Property(tType, propertyName);
    var selectExpression =
        Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TResult>>(property, tType)
                  .Compile();
    return (await dataTask).Select(selectExpression);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Isn't it possible to do this

```
 var retval =  data.Select(t => mn.GetValue(t, null));
```