# how to get value of a definite Column name in c# / Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I want to know if it possible to get value of a definite columns name ?
For exemple `SELECT NAME FROM PERSON;`

```
string NAME; <--- Column name
string fundPerson;
fundPerson = context.PERSON.Where(a => a... == NAME);
```

The problem is that the column name can change, it is not always the "NAME" column.
Hence I need a solution where I can dynamically pass a column name to the query.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to the source code in C# to create a linq query that compiles to `SELECT NAME FROM PERSON` under Linq to SQL or Linq to Entity Framework?

```
IEnumerable<string> names = from x in context.PERSONS
                            select x.Name;
```

OR

```
IEnumerable<string> names = context.PERSONS.Select(x => x.Name);
```

In Monad parlance you want a projection onto the Name property.

EDIT : You want to dynamically state which column?

```
string columnName = "Name";
ParameterExpression personExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "p");
Expression<Func<Person, string>> column = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, string>>(Expression.PropertyOrField(personExpression, columnName), personExpression);

IEnumerable<string> things = context.PERSONS.Select(column);
```

Comment: Yes but when i do this i do have an error on the Expression.Lambda<Person, string> it say that the non generic method cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: Sorry missed out the inner `Func`.

Comment: Now i do have this error on this Expression.Lambda<Func<PERSON, string>>(Expression.PropertyOrField(personExpression, columnName), personExpression); The best overloaded method match for …. has some invalid arguments

Comment: Ah crap...`Expression personExpression` should actually be `ParameterExpression personExpression`.

Comment: is this possible to edit the answer because i never do expression and i can't understand Plx ?

Comment: I don't no when you will go to Switzerland but if you will go you have to know that a beer is waiting you ;-)

Comment: I have tried it, but somehow it does not work for me. Error `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<MyNamespace.Person>.Select(string, params System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter[])' has some invalid arguments

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T,string>>' to 'string'` which occurs in the last line of your example. What could be wrong?

Comment: You need to import 'using System.Linq'. The method is an extension method in 'System.Linq.Queryable'.

Comment: You have a generic that isn't being make concrete.

Comment: I did, but I am still getting the error (I was trying it with [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)). The statement `names = context.PERSONS.Select(x => x.Name);` works so that proves that System.Linq is imported properly. Only `.Select(column);` does not work.

Comment: You lambda is on type T not User.

Comment: You are right, thank you for the hint - I was trying to make it generic by using the code inside `IQueryable<string> test<T>(string columnName)`, hence I replaced PERSON inside by T. But that was the issue as you found ... now it is solved. Sorry if that caused confusion. I gave you a +1 for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
fundPerson = context.PERSON.Where(a=>a... == NAME).Select(a=>a.NAME).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: The problem is that the column name can change, it is not always the " NAME" colomn

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit misleading.. Are you after a collection of names, like what you would get from running the SQL "SELECT Name FROM Person"?

If so, using Linq-to-sql syntax:

```
var people = from p in context.PERSON select a.NAME;
```

If you're trying to find a specific person, based on the NAME string?

```
string name = "barry";
var person = from p in context.PERSON select a where a.NAME.Contains(name);
```