# How to build dynamic Linq query ?

Tags: c#, linq

What can I do to dynamically create queries when I do have this type of string ?

I want to transform this :

> SELECT [Extent1].[TASK_ORDER] AS [TASK_ORDER] FROM [dbo].[CR_TASK] AS [Extent1]

to this :

> context.CR_TASK.Where(a => a.TASK_NO == id).Select(a => a.TASK_NO);

Comment: That looks like a __static__ transformation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905823/how-to-get-value-of-a-definite-column-name-in-c-sharp-linq/22905946#22905946

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [dynamic linq](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/) (http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/) easily which is capable of doing all dynamic operations on linq and strings

Comment: how can we use this reference ?

Comment: Download from the site, extract it, add the library (dll) into your project, see the sample (on the site), write your queries.

Comment: Or you can get it using NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Library.  This is more current and if you use .NET 4.0+, it adds support for the dynamic keyword.