# How to get a value of a column name in C# / Linq and then place the values in your own class

Tags: c#, linq

This is very similar to this question:
[how to get value of a definite Column name in c# / Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905823/how-to-get-value-of-a-definite-column-name-in-c-sharp-linq)

The difference is that I am trying fill in a list of the GraphPoint class class:

```
public class GraphPoint
{
    public DateTime DateTimePoint { get; set; }
    public double ValuePoint { get; set; }

    public GraphPoint()
    {

    }

    public GraphPoint(DateTime dateTimePoint, double valuePoint)
    {
        DateTimePoint = dateTimePoint;
        ValuePoint = valuePoint;
    }
}
```

Here is some code that code that I am trying to get to work:

```
List<GraphPoint> graphPoints = null;
ParameterExpression doubleExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "p");
Expression<Func<DirD, double>> column = Expression.Lambda<Func<DirD, double>> 
    (Expression.PropertyOrField(doubleExpression, file.Title), doubleExpression);
IEnumerable<double> things = context.DirDs.Select(column);
graphPoints = context.Dirds.Select(s => new GraphPoint(s => Time, column)).ToList();
```

I think I am fairly close to doing what I need to do...but just having trouble with the exact syntax.
Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Just create a new list of initialize GraphPoint objects? And what is not working about the code you posted?

Comment: So you have got an enumerable of doubles to set into ValuePoint. Where does the vale for DateTimePoint come form? Is it a separate enumerable? Can you post some sample data?

Comment: I need to get a list of these GraphPoints.  I need to get this from a table in a database.  I know I will be using the Time column, however I do not know until runtime what the column name will be.  So I need to at runtime alter a string name of the column I want into a actual column.  The context.Drad.Select(s => new GraphPoint(s => Time, column)).ToList(); is incorrect.

Comment: Lets say my table had these columns with data   Time 11:30, 12:00, 9:00   ColumnA 1.1, 2.2, 3.3    ColumnB 4.2, 2, 1.2  I do not know until runtime if I want to use the data in ColumnA or ColumnB.  But let's say during runtime I want to used ColumnB.  Then I want to use {11:30, 4.2}, {12:00, 2}, {9:00, 1.2} for the values in my List of GraphPoints.

Comment: Is there just a small number of columns you have to choose from? Are the possible names of the columns known at compile time?

Comment: The tables and columns will be known at compile time but there are many...perhaps over a 100.  Also there is a potential in the future to increase the number of tables and columns. If I can get the code to generate this during runtime it will make this section of code future proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically build an lambda expression using [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) that will get the value of a property on your entity. Something like this will work for any property type on any entity type.

```
// T is the entity type, TProp is the poperty type
private static Func<T, TProp> Getter<T, TProp>(string propertyName)
{
    Type entityType = typeof(T);
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = entityType.GetProperty(propertyName);

    var getterMethodInfo = propertyInfo.GetGetMethod();
    var entity = Expression.Parameter(entityType);
    var getterCall = Expression.Call(entity, getterMethodInfo);

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(getterCall, entity);
    var functionThatGetsValue = (Func<T, TProp>)lambda.Compile();

    return functionThatGetsValue; 
}
```

Once that delegate is built, you can use it in your projection like so:

```
static void Main()
{
    //context.Dirds
    List<Row> Dirds = new List<Row> { 
            new Row {
            Time = DateTime.Parse("2014-01-01 11:30"),
            ColumnA = 1.1,
            ColumnB = 4.2
        },

        new Row {
            Time = DateTime.Parse("2014-01-01 12:00"),
            ColumnA = 2.2,
            ColumnB = 2.0
        },

        new Row {
            Time = DateTime.Parse("2014-01-01 09:00"),
            ColumnA = 3.3,
            ColumnB = 1.2
        }
    };

    // Build a "getter" for the column that contains the double
    var getter = Getter<Row, double>("ColumnB");

    var results = Dirds.Select(r => new GraphPoint {
        DateTimePoint = r.Time,
        ValuePoint = getter(r)
    });

    foreach(GraphPoint point in results)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", point.DateTimePoint, point.ValuePoint);

}
```

Here are the types I used in the example above:

```
public class Row
{
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public double ColumnA { get; set; }
    public double ColumnB { get; set; }
}

public class GraphPoint
{
    public DateTime DateTimePoint { get; set; }
    public double ValuePoint { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks!  Just tested that out and that works great!  I think I am going to have to get up to speed on Expression Trees.