# Using reflection to obtain values based on a specific query condition

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics, reflection

I have a slightly different issue to the one answered here ([Using reflection to retrieve a value from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863508/using-reflection-to-retrieve-a-value-from-a-list?noredirect=1#comment34999250_22863508))

While the approved answer here works fine for select, I'd like to extend it so that I can obtain data from a query based on a condition type. Currently, my adapted code looks like this

```
 public static async Task<T> GetDataFromTable<T>(string paramName, string condition="")
    {
        var k = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        var mn = typeof(T).GetProperty(paramName);
        var tc = typeof(T).GetProperty(condition);
        if (mn == null || !ftrackData.Online)
            return (T)k;
        var data = GetTableData<T>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(paramName))
        {
            var retval = data.Select(t => mn.GetValue(t, null));
            return (T)retval;
        }
        else
            return (T)data.FirstOrDefault(t => mn.GetValue(t, null) > tc.GetType(t, null)).ToList();
    }
```

I'd be looking to have the ">" in the final return change depending on an additional parameter passed into the arguments list. I know I can do a simple switch after the else, but is there some way to change the condition by insertion?

Comment: Using an [Expression Tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) you can dynamically change your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't really make any sense. The `Select` extension method takes a `Func<T, TResult>` which implies the return type should be `IEnumerable<TResult>` whereas you specify it as `T`.

In your question you want to do a `Select` and `FirstOrDefault` in the same method, but that is not possible since the result types will be different.

`Select`:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> SelectData<T, TResult>(
    string propertyName
)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<TResult>();
    }

    var dataTask = GetTableData<T>();

    var tType = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
    var property = Expression.Property(tType, propertyName);
    var selectExpression =
        Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TResult>>(property, tType)
                  .Compile();
    return (await dataTask).Select(selectExpression);
}
```

`FirstOrDefault`:

```
public static async Task<T> FirstOrDefaultData<T>(
    string propertyName,
    string conditionName,
    Func<MemberExpression, MemberExpression, BinaryExpression> comparer
)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName) ||
       string.IsNullOrWhileSpace(conditionName) ||
       comparer == null
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    var dataTask = GetTableData<T>();

    var tType = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
    var property = Expression.Property(tType, propertyName);
    var condition = Expression.Property(tType, conditionName);
    var binaryExpression =
        Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(comparer(property, condition), tType)
                  .Compile();
    return (await dataTask).FirstOrDefault(binaryExpression);
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public bool Flag { get; set; }
}

var bars = SelectData<Foo, string>("Bar");
var foo = FirstOrDefaultData<Foo>("Bar",
                                  "Flag",
                                  (p, c) => Expression.GreaterThan(p, c));
```

Comment: Thanks for such a complete answer - thanks, explains a lot :)